# Intel compiler vectorisation report: heavy-overhead vs. lightweight?

Tags: fortran, sse, simd, intel-fortran, auto-vectorization

In this vectorization report from Intel's Fortran compiler:

```
LOOP BEGIN at MLFMATranslationProd.f90(38,2)
  remark #15399: vectorization support: unroll factor set to 4
  remark #15300: LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
  remark #15462: unmasked indexed (or gather) loads: 2
  remark #15475: --- begin vector loop cost summary ---
  remark #15476: scalar loop cost: 12
  remark #15477: vector loop cost: 20.000
  remark #15478: estimated potential speedup: 2.340
  remark #15479: lightweight vector operations: 5
  remark #15481: heavy-overhead vector operations: 1
  remark #15488: --- end vector loop cost summary ---
LOOP END
```

What are the meanings of `lightweight vector` and `heavy-overhead vector` operations here?

The relevant loop looks like

```
do ir=1,N(lev) 
    G1(lev)%D(ir) = 0.d0 
    G2(lev)%D(ir) = 0.d0 
enddo
```

with `lev` some integer.

Comment: This is with Intel's Fortran compiler?  I edited your question to clarify (and maybe get the attention of people who might know the answer).

Comment: It would make your question much better if showed also the code of the loop. Now someone has to guess what kind of operations you might have there instead of just pointing them out.

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies, it is simple loop:                                                      do ir=1,N(lev)
  G1(lev)%D(ir) = 0.d0
  G2(lev)%D(ir) = 0.d0
enddo
where lev is equal to some integer. And yes, it is with Intel's Fortran compiler.

Comment: In fact, I want to know what is the meaning of light, medium and heavy weight operations in vectorisation report. Thanks

Comment: In past versions of ifort, "heavy-overhead" terminology was used to refer to combinations of parallel and serial instructions.

Comment: What is `G1` and what is `D`? What type? Allocatable? Pointer? Of course `lev` is integer, but that is not too much important.

Comment: These are arrays and allocatable  with double type.

Comment: So show the code defining them! We don't have a crystal ball.

Comment: Thanks mate for your comment, but can you please tell me whats the meaning of light, medium or heavy vector operations based on the vectorization report? I am not concerned about the numbers of light or heavy vector operations, I just want to know the meaning or the explanations of those? Thanks again for your consideration.

Comment: @Hamid not all vector operations cost the same in terms of cycles -- that is likely to be the distinction there. Maybe could you post the assembly code associated to that portion of code?

Comment: @Harald Thanks for your reply.